# Display mpld3 chart in HTML with django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, matplotlib

I'm using mpld3 to display matplotlib charts inside an HTML page via django. I use mpld3.fig_to_dict method to produce a string from a matplotlib figure and save it in a JSON variable .

I don't know how to call the JSON variable in HTML

```
<div id="fig01"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var json01 = { <snip JSON code> };
mpld3.draw_figure("fig01", json01);
</script>
```

The json variable created in views.py:

```
json01 = json.dumps(mpld3.fig_to_dict(fig))
return render_to_response('plot/main.html', json01)
```

This code returns a blank HTML page. 
I also tried to call JSON variable like this but it also don't work

```
var json01 = "{{json01}}";
```

I think that the problem is coming from the javascript variable because when i set the chart points in javascript everything works

Answer (score 5):

the answer is...
in views.py:

```
js_data = json.dumps(mpld3.fig_to_dict(fig))
return render_to_response('plot.html', {"my_data": js_data})
```

and in template:

```
graph = {{ my_data|safe }};

mpld3.draw_figure("fig01", graph);
```